# Levenshtein distance & OEIS (Cops)

Tags: number, sequence, cops-and-robbers, edit-distance

This is the Cop post. The [Robber post is here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/146927/31516).

---

Your task is to take an integer input **N** and output the **Nth** digit in the sequence [OEIS A002942](http://oeis.org/A002942).

The sequence consists of the square numbers written backwards:

```
1, 4, 9, 61, 52, 63, 94, 46, 18, 1, 121, 441, ...
```

Note that leading zeros are trimmed away (**100** becomes **1**, not **001**). Concatenating this into a string (or one long number gives):

```
1496152639446181121441
```

You shall output the **Nth** digit in this string/number. You may choose to take **N** as 0-indexed or 1-indexed (please state which one you choose).

#### Test cases (1-indexed):

```
N = 1,      ==> 1
N = 5,      ==> 1
N = 17,     ==> 1   <- Important test case! It's not zero.
N = 20,     ==> 4
N = 78,     ==> 0
N = 100,    ==> 4
```

Your code should work for numbers up to **N = 2^15** (unless your language can't handles 32 bit integers by default, in which case **N** can be lower).

---

#### Cops:

You must write two functions/programs, in the same language, that do the same thing. You have to post one of the functions/programs, as well as the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between the two functions/programs you have written. The Levenshtein distance is measured in characters (so addition of a two byte character will give a LD = 1).

The unrevealed code can not be longer than the original solution (but it can be the same size). The robbers will attempt to write a code with the exact Levenshtein distance you gave (it can be different from your unrevealed code, as long as it works).

The winner will be the uncracked submission that has the lowest Levenshtein distance.

You may [check the Levenshtein distance here!](https://planetcalc.com/1720/)

---

If your submission goes uncracked for 7 days then you may reveal the alternative code you have written and mark your submission as safe.

---

Comment: Yes, I'll add that to the rules. :)

Comment: You talk about scripts, but I assume this is the default _program or function_?

Comment: Yes, default everything :)

Comment: How are you handling comments and whitespace, I see some weird stuff.

Comment: Handing comments and whitespace is part of the cops' challenge.

Comment: "Your code should work for numbers up to N = 2^15" -> but one of the test cases is larger than that. Is the 274164 case necessary?

Comment: @TomCarpenter what do you gain? I think you need 32bit integers for the squares with N=2^15 already?

Comment: Characters rather than bytes: how does that work with RPL? A command is stored using 2.5 bytes, whether it's `+` or `CONVERT`, and that 20-bit number has nothing to do with '+' or letters in the word 'convert'. Is it nevertheless the case that `DUP 2` (2.5 byte command and 2.5 byte number) differs from `DUP2` (another 2.5 byte command) by just 1 (+space) while `+` and `CONVERT` (each 2.5 byte command) differ by 7 (change '+' into one letter and add 6 letters)? Even stranger, `CONVERT` and `CONVERTS`: a 2.5 byte command and a variable name, 11.5 bytes: distance 1 despite longer by 9 bytes?

Comment: Just to clarify, to edit a program, the program is converted into characters, you edit them, then it's parsed and converted back into its binary representation.

Comment: How about Spectrum BASIC - does PRINT count as 1 character or 5? It's stored as 1 byte and edited (entered/deleted) like a character, that's you can't just delete R to get PINT... It has its own code (8-bit extension of ASCII). A string " PRINT " has LEN 1.

Comment: @Heimdall I don't know! Feel free to post an answer and explain in detail how you calculate the Levenshtein distance. It won't be eligible for the win, sorry... But the fun is in playing :)

Comment: Yes, fun is in the playing. But I can't help being competitive. I guess what makes the most sense is how it's edited. So with Spectrum BASIC I'll assume keywords are single character and with RPL on HP48 I'll assume the commands are made out of individual characters. You asked the question, you decide on interpretation of rules, so I guess it's up to you whether entries in those languages are eligible...

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), LD = 13, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/146966/56433)

```hs
((snd.span(<'1').reverse.show.(^2)=<<[1..])!!)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc3RCoIwFIDhe59iQuCE43C2XILrEbrp0gyGzYzUhrO6iF69FTMQOpcf/zmnkeai2tbWYm8xNv2RGC17nAc0CMmg7mowipjm@iD4kIQizwtKSBn6fmg7ee6RQPo27sYBLVAnNapRwYCmQDPgHLIMEs5ouiy9Z@Rtv/EKkBshNog6oRz@JIlnYU74epZ42oqnaG7cIwa/O9HLvqu6lSdjo0rrDw)

I double-checked that leading zeros are trimmed ;)

**Explanation:**

```hs
                    [1..]     -- for each element in [1,2,3,4,5,...]
                 =<<          -- apply the following functions 
             (^2)             -- square [1,4,9,16,25,...]
           show.              -- convert to string ["1","4","9","16","25",...]
       reverse.               -- reverse ["1","4","9","61","52",...,"001",...]
   span(<'1').                -- split into leading zeros and remainder [("","1"),("","4"),...,("00","1"),...]
  snd.                        -- only keep remainder ["1","4","9","61","52",...,"1",...]
                              -- and concatenate the result "1496152..."
((                       )!!) -- index into the sequence
```

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/146966/71256)!

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), LD = 103 ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/146992/3852))

Using such a high Levenshtein distance is probably not the best strategy, but let's try it anyway.

```
n => { for(i = 0, str = ''; i <= n; i++) { str += +[...i * i + ''].reverse().join(''); } return str[n]; }
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

n => { for(i = 0, str = ''; i <= n; i++) { str += +[...i * i + ''].reverse().join(''); } return str[n]; }

console.log(f(5))      // 1
console.log(f(17))     // 1
console.log(f(20))     // 4
console.log(f(78))     // 0
console.log(f(100))    // 4
console.log(f(274164)) // 1
```

#### Intended solution

```js
$=>eval(atob`Wy4uLkFycmF5KCQrMSldLm1hcCgoXyxpKT0+K1suLi5pKmkrJyddLnJldmVyc2UoKS5qb2luYGApLmpvaW5gYFskXQ`)
```

Encoded part:

```js
[...Array($+1)].map((_,i)=>+[...i*i+''].reverse().join``).join``[$]
```

Comment: Does this strip leading 0s after reversing?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Yes. The unary `+` ensures that the reversed string is coerced to a Number.

Comment: Ohhhh... wow, that's harder than I thought.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/146992/3852)!

Answer (score 3):

## [cQuents 0](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents/tree/cquents-0), LD = 1, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/146961/65836)

```
":\r$*$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/X8kqpkhFS@X/f0MDAyMA)

I thought this didn't work for leading zeroes, but it actually does - the reverse function in cQuents is coded as `int(reversed(str(n)))`.

### Explanation

```
"         Concatenate sequence together, get nth term in the string instead of the sequence
 :        Mode: Sequence: given input n, output the nth term, 1-indexed
          Each term in the sequences equals:
  \r      reverse(
    $*$           the index * the index
                  or
    $$            the index * the index
                   ) (implicit)
```

Comment: [cracked?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/146961/56433)

Comment: @Laikoni yep, cQuents does implicit multiplication like, kinda like Mathematica, but you don't need the spaces. Adding an explanation.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 104 bytes, LD=21 [Invalid AND Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/146927/levenshtein-distance-oeis-robbers/147015#147015)

```
d=lambda y:y if'0'!=str(y)[-1]else d(y/10)
lambda n:''.join([str(d(x*x))[::-1]for x in range(1,n)])[n-1]
```

<s>P.S. Is an unlimited amount of whitespace and commenting allowed? If so this will not be hard to crack.</s>

Comment: "The unrevealed code can not be longer than the original solution."

Comment: @Scrooble I saw that but I don't think it will be hard to make a program that is much shorter than this one. Already been done in python 3 in another answer and it works in python 2 so all they need to add is a bunch of `\n`s (about 50)

Comment: Wouldn't 50 newlines exceed a Levenshtein distance of 21?

Comment: @Scrooble You are very right I got confused and was thinking about the problem incorrectly. Thanks

Comment: This seems to error on inputs lower than 5

Comment: Anyway, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/147015/62393)

Comment: @Leo Oops. Should I delete the post since it's not valid? I guess you're a super robber. Not sure how I missed that, I remember trying those cases

Comment: I'd say don't delete it: you're "cracked" anyways and the robber deserves credit :)

Answer (score 3):

## [6502 machine code](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/6502_Assembly) (C64), LD = 1 ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/147643/71420))

```
00 C0 20 FD AE A0 00 99 5B 00 C8 20 73 00 90 F7 99 5B 00 A2 0B CA 88 30 09 B9
5B 00 29 0F 95 5B 10 F3 A9 00 95 5B CA 10 F9 A9 00 A0 03 99 69 00 88 10 FA A0
20 A2 76 18 B5 E6 90 02 09 10 4A 95 E6 E8 10 F4 A2 03 76 69 CA 10 FB 88 F0 11
A2 09 B5 5C C9 08 30 04 E9 03 95 5C CA 10 F3 30 D6 A2 03 B5 69 95 57 CA 10 F9
A9 01 85 FB A2 03 A9 00 95 FB CA D0 FB A2 03 B5 FB 95 22 95 26 CA 10 F7 A9 00
A2 03 95 69 CA 10 FB A0 20 A2 02 46 25 76 22 CA 10 FB 90 0C A2 7C 18 B5 AA 75
ED 95 ED E8 10 F7 A2 7D 06 26 36 AA E8 10 FB 88 10 DD A0 0B A9 00 99 5A 00 88
D0 FA A0 20 A2 09 B5 5C C9 05 30 04 69 02 95 5C CA 10 F3 06 69 A2 FD 36 6D E8
D0 FB A2 09 B5 5C 2A C9 10 29 0F 95 5C CA 10 F4 88 D0 D7 E0 0A F0 05 E8 B5 5B
F0 F7 09 30 99 5B 00 C8 E8 E0 0B F0 04 B5 5B 90 F1 88 B9 5B 00 C9 30 F0 F8 A2
7C 18 B5 DB E9 00 95 DB E8 10 F7 90 14 88 30 05 B9 5B 00 D0 EA A2 7C F6 7F D0
03 E8 10 F9 4C 73 C0 B9 5B 00 4C D2 FF
```

**[Online demo](https://vice.janicek.co/c64/#%7B"controlPort2":"joystick","primaryControlPort":2,"keys":%7B"SPACE":"","RETURN":"","F1":"","F3":"","F5":"","F7":""%7D,"files":%7B"sqdig.prg":"data:;base64,AMAg/a6gAJlbAMggcwCQ95lbAKILyogwCblbACkPlVsQ86kAlVvKEPmpAKADmWkAiBD6oCCidhi15pACCRBKleboEPSiA3ZpyhD7iPARogm1XMkIMATpA5VcyhDzMNaiA7VplVfKEPmpAYX7ogOpAJX7ytD7ogO1+5UilSbKEPepAKIDlWnKEPugIKICRiV2IsoQ+5AMonwYtap17ZXt6BD3on0GJjaq6BD7iBDdoAupAJlaAIjQ+qAgogm1XMkFMARpApVcyhDzBmmi/TZt6ND7ogm1XCrJECkPlVzKEPSI0NfgCvAF6LVb8PcJMJlbAMjo4AvwBLVbkPGIuVsAyTDw+KJ8GLXb6QCV2+gQ95AUiDAFuVsA0OqifPZ/0APoEPlMc8C5WwBM0v8="%7D,"vice":%7B"-autostart":"sqdig.prg"%7D%7D)**, usage: `sys49152,n` where `n` is the 0-indexed input.

---

For the last test case, you need a bit of patience, as this poor machine has to do millions of bit-shifts and additions to present you the result ;)

The language here is the machine code, so LD is measured in this format -- nevertheless, to give something to start with, here's the program in [`ca65`](http://cc65.github.io/cc65/) assembler source:

```
NUMSIZE         = 4     ; 32 bit integers ...
NUMSTRSIZE      = 11    ; need up to 11 characters for 0-terminated string

.segment "ZPUSR": zeropage
v_x:            .res    NUMSIZE         ; next number to be squared

.segment "ZPFAC": zeropage
v_n:            .res    NUMSIZE         ; input index (0-based), counts down
nc_string:      .res    NUMSTRSIZE      ; string buffer for numbers

.segment "ZPTMP": zeropage
mpm_arg1:       .res    NUMSIZE         ; arg1 for multiplication
mpm_arg2:       .res    NUMSIZE         ; arg2 for multiplication

.segment "ZPFAC2": zeropage
mpm_res:        .res    NUMSIZE         ; numeric result (mult and str convert)

; load address for creating a C64 .PRG file:

.segment "LDADDR"
                .word   $c000

.code

; first read number from command argument and convert to unsigned
; integer in little-endian:

                jsr     $aefd
                ldy     #$00
rn_loop:        sta     nc_string,y
                iny
                jsr     $73
                bcc     rn_loop
                sta     nc_string,y
                ldx     #NUMSTRSIZE
stn_copybcd:    dex
                dey
                bmi     stn_fillzero
                lda     nc_string,y
                and     #$f
                sta     nc_string,x
                bpl     stn_copybcd
stn_fillzero:   lda     #$0
                sta     nc_string,x
                dex
                bpl     stn_fillzero
                lda     #$0
                ldy     #(NUMSIZE-1)
stn_znumloop:   sta     mpm_res,y
                dey
                bpl     stn_znumloop
                ldy     #(NUMSIZE*8)
stn_loop:       ldx     #($81-NUMSTRSIZE)
                clc
stn_rorloop:    lda     nc_string+NUMSTRSIZE+$80,x
                bcc     stn_skipbit
                ora     #$10
stn_skipbit:    lsr     a
                sta     nc_string+NUMSTRSIZE+$80,x
                inx
                bpl     stn_rorloop
                ldx     #(NUMSIZE-1)
stn_ror:        ror     mpm_res,x
                dex
                bpl     stn_ror
                dey
                beq     main
stn_sub:        ldx     #(NUMSTRSIZE-2)
stn_subloop:    lda     nc_string+1,x
                cmp     #$8
                bmi     stn_nosub
                sbc     #$3
                sta     nc_string+1,x
stn_nosub:      dex
                bpl     stn_subloop
                bmi     stn_loop

main:
                ldx     #(NUMSIZE-1)
argloop:        lda     mpm_res,x
                sta     v_n,x
                dex
                bpl     argloop
                lda     #$01
                sta     v_x
                ldx     #(NUMSIZE-1)
                lda     #$00
initxloop:      sta     v_x,x
                dex
                bne     initxloop

mainloop:

; prepare arguments for multiplication:

                ldx     #(NUMSIZE-1)
sqrargloop:     lda     v_x,x
                sta     mpm_arg1,x
                sta     mpm_arg2,x
                dex
                bpl     sqrargloop

; do multiplication:

                lda     #$00
                ldx     #(NUMSIZE-1)
mul_clearloop:  sta     mpm_res,x
                dex
                bpl     mul_clearloop
                ldy     #(NUMSIZE*8)
mul_loop:       ldx     #(NUMSIZE-2)
                lsr     mpm_arg1+NUMSIZE-1
mul_rorloop:    ror     mpm_arg1,x
                dex
                bpl     mul_rorloop
                bcc     mul_noadd
                ldx     #($80-NUMSIZE)
                clc
mul_addloop:    lda     mpm_arg2+NUMSIZE+$80,x
                adc     mpm_res+NUMSIZE+$80,x
                sta     mpm_res+NUMSIZE+$80,x
                inx
                bpl     mul_addloop
mul_noadd:      ldx     #($81-NUMSIZE)
                asl     mpm_arg2
mul_rolloop:    rol     mpm_arg2+NUMSIZE+$80,x
                inx
                bpl     mul_rolloop
                dey
                bpl     mul_loop

; convert result to string:

                ldy     #NUMSTRSIZE
                lda     #$0
nts_fillzero:   sta     nc_string-1,y
                dey
                bne     nts_fillzero
                ldy     #(NUMSIZE*8)
nts_bcdloop:    ldx     #(NUMSTRSIZE-2)
nts_addloop:    lda     nc_string+1,x
                cmp     #$5
                bmi     nts_noadd
                adc     #$2
                sta     nc_string+1,x
nts_noadd:      dex
                bpl     nts_addloop
                asl     mpm_res
                ldx     #($ff-NUMSIZE+2)
nts_rol:        rol     mpm_res+NUMSIZE,x       ; + $100 w/o zp wraparound
                inx
                bne     nts_rol
                ldx     #(NUMSTRSIZE-2)
nts_rolloop:    lda     nc_string+1,x
                rol     a
                cmp     #$10
                and     #$f
                sta     nc_string+1,x
nts_rolnext:    dex
                bpl     nts_rolloop
                dey
                bne     nts_bcdloop
nts_scan:       cpx     #(NUMSTRSIZE-1)
                beq     nts_copydigits
                inx
                lda     nc_string,x
                beq     nts_scan
nts_copydigits: ora     #$30
                sta     nc_string,y
                iny
                inx
                cpx     #(NUMSTRSIZE)
                beq     strip0loop
                lda     nc_string,x
                bcc     nts_copydigits

; search for first non-0 character from the end of the string:

strip0loop:     dey
                lda     nc_string,y
                cmp     #$30
                beq     strip0loop

; decrement n for each digit:

founddigit:
                ldx     #($80-NUMSIZE)
                clc
decnloop:       lda     v_n+NUMSIZE+$80,x
                sbc     #$00
                sta     v_n+NUMSIZE+$80,x
                inx
                bpl     decnloop
                bcc     foundresult

                dey
                bmi     next_x
                lda     nc_string,y
                bne     founddigit

; increment x to calculate next square number:

next_x:
                ldx     #($80-NUMSIZE)
incxloop:       inc     v_x+NUMSIZE-$80,x
                bne     incxdone
                inx
                bpl     incxloop
incxdone:       jmp     mainloop

foundresult:    lda     nc_string,y
                jmp     $ffd2
```

... and here's the linker script for `ld65`:

```
MEMORY {
  LDADDR: start = $bffe, size = 2;
  CODE: start = $c000, size = $1000;
  ZPTMP: start = $0022, size = $0008;
  ZPFAC: start = $0057, size = $000f;
  ZPFAC2: start = $0069, size = $0004;
  ZPUSR: start = $00fb, size = $0004;
}

SEGMENTS {
  LDADDR: load = LDADDR;
  CODE: load = CODE;
  ZPTMP: load = ZPTMP, type = zp;
  ZPFAC: load = ZPFAC, type = zp;
  ZPFAC2: load = ZPFAC2, type = zp;
  ZPUSR: load = ZPUSR, type = zp;
}
```

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/147643/75557) (I believe)

Comment: @Jo. yes, edited.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 59 + 1 (`-a`) = 60 bytes, LD=55

```perl
$j.=int reverse$_**2for 1..$_;$_--;say$j=~s/.{$_}(.).*/$1/r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEADAr3TYQwmuGkQH8Qm9QToYKJGyShBRT2@bKYH2iRkSuni0jsIZqAbwQoxbps4ggrfgpbR1vSC5tyq8wT89DigUGEXMZv5yaTEfleUyoTaa5foD)

Comment: maybe cracked, I'm not sure of my entry https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/146927/levenshtein-distance-oeis-robbers/147045#147045

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, (177 bytes) LD = 92 ([Cracked by *@Arnauld*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/147074/52210))

([Ive used this online LD-calculator.](https://planetcalc.com/1721/))

```java
n->{String r="",t=r;for(int i=1,j;r.length()<=n+1;i++)if(Math.sqrt(i)%1==0){for(t="",j=(i+"").length();j>0;t+=(i+"").charAt(--j));r+=t.replaceAll("^0+","");}return r.charAt(n);}
```

This is probably not too hard if you simply golf this. :)

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##hVHLasMwELz3KxZDQUK2iduQEFQF8gHJJcfSguooiVxFdtfrQDH@dlfOo7dg0B40O7PszBb6rJOyMr7Yffe503UNa219@wRgPRnc69zAZvgC5EeNkLOAg@cyQF2o8GrSZHPYgAcFvU@W7ZbQ@gOgiqKYFMp9iReZVVlcSEyd8Qc6Mv6mvMikFYLbPVtrOqb1DxKz/DlTasLbQUfDkEIxK6KI/ytlsZxIEnd4WG1FLEkKziUKRSmayoXdV86x6HMiojjQZIeGGvSAd0Hw0fXyaqNqvlywcXNzLu0OTiEKdjXz/gGaX3PY/tZkTmnZUFqFFjnPfJqzKb@E8rCfzcYIixHCfD5CWIxNeJlPs9krv12v6/8A)

```java
n->{                             // Method with integer parameter and character return-type
  String r="",                   //  Result-String, starting empty
         t=r;                    //  Temp-String, starting empty
  for(int i=1,j;                 //  Index-integers
      r.length()<=n+1;i++)       //  Loop (1) as long as the length is at least n+1
    if(Math.sqrt(i)%1==0){       //   If the current number `i` is a perfect square:
      for(t="",                  //    Reset the temp-String to empty
          j=(i+"").length();     //    Set `j` to the length of the current number
          j>0;                   //    Inner loop (2) as long as `j` is larger than 0
        t+=                      //     Append the temp-String with:
           (i+"").charAt(--j)    //     The digit of integer `i` at index `j-1`
                                 //     (by first decrease `j` with 1 with `--j`)
      );                         //    End of inner loop (2)
      r+=t                       //    And then append the temp-String to the result-String
          .replaceAll("^0+","");}//    after we've removed any leading zeroes
                                 //  End of loop (1) (implicit / single-line body)
  return r.charAt(n);            //  Return the `n`'th character of the result-String
}                                // End of method
```

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/147074/58563)

Comment: Intended solution: `n->{String r="";for(int i=1;r.length()<=n+1;r+=new Long(new StringBuffer(i*i+++"").reverse()+""));return r.charAt(n);}` (**118 bytes, 92 LD**)

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), LD = 63, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/147117/42295)

```matlab
@(t)[arrayfun(@(t)num2str(str2num(flip(num2str(t)))),(1:t).^2,'uni',0){:}](t)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYmNBsMwFIUfJ/cSkYRJhdH3qJaYXcqaVnpTqvrsWTJ2OJ/zs744HO9CT6VU6YFxCCmFk3KE1mJe7M4Jqm3NQJ95g//IWCXBeEY1WSlynIXUePl7rF8ZCAxKgkeDcY1WN7rut2iNoyhf)

The submission is 77 bytes, so you need to substitute quite a bit =)

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/147117/42295).

Answer (score 2):

## [6502 machine code](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/6502_Assembly) (C64), LD = 1, safe

```
00 C0 20 FD AE A0 00 99 5B 00 C8 20 73 00 90 F7 99 5B 00 A2 0B CA 98 88 30 09
B9 5B 00 29 0F 95 5B 10 F2 95 5B CA 10 FB A0 20 A2 76 18 B5 E6 90 02 09 10 4A
95 E6 E8 10 F4 A2 03 76 69 CA 10 FB 88 F0 11 A2 09 B5 5C C9 08 30 04 E9 03 95
5C CA 10 F3 30 D6 A2 03 B5 69 95 57 CA 10 F9 A9 01 85 FB A2 03 A9 00 95 FB CA
D0 FB A2 03 B5 FB 95 22 95 26 CA 10 F7 A9 00 A2 03 95 69 CA 10 FB A0 20 A2 02
46 25 76 22 CA 10 FB 90 0C A2 7C 18 B5 AA 75 ED 95 ED E8 10 F7 A2 7D 06 26 36
AA E8 10 FB 88 10 DD A2 0B A9 00 95 5A CA D0 FB A0 20 A2 09 B5 5C C9 05 30 04
69 02 95 5C CA 10 F3 06 69 A2 FD 36 6D E8 D0 FB A2 09 B5 5C 2A C9 10 29 0F 95
5C CA 10 F4 88 D0 D7 E8 B5 5B F0 FB 09 30 99 5B 00 C8 E8 E0 0B F0 04 B5 5B 90
F1 88 B9 5B 00 C9 30 F0 F8 A2 7C 18 B5 DB E9 00 95 DB E8 10 F7 90 14 88 30 05
B9 5B 00 D0 EA A2 7C F6 7F D0 03 E8 10 F9 4C 68 C0 B9 5B 00 4C D2 FF
```

**[Online demo](https://vice.janicek.co/c64/#%7B"controlPort2":"joystick","primaryControlPort":2,"keys":%7B"SPACE":"","RETURN":"","F1":"","F3":"","F5":"","F7":""%7D,"files":%7B"sqdig.prg":"data:;base64,AMAg/a6gAJlbAMggcwCQ95lbAKILypiIMAm5WwApD5VbEPKVW8oQ+6AgonYYteaQAgkQSpXm6BD0ogN2acoQ+4jwEaIJtVzJCDAE6QOVXMoQ8zDWogO1aZVXyhD5qQGF+6IDqQCV+8rQ+6IDtfuVIpUmyhD3qQCiA5VpyhD7oCCiAkYldiLKEPuQDKJ8GLWqde2V7egQ96J9BiY2qugQ+4gQ3aILqQCVWsrQ+6Agogm1XMkFMARpApVcyhDzBmmi/TZt6ND7ogm1XCrJECkPlVzKEPSI0NfotVvw+wkwmVsAyOjgC/AEtVuQ8Yi5WwDJMPD4onwYtdvpAJXb6BD3kBSIMAW5WwDQ6qJ89n/QA+gQ+UxowLlbAEzS/w=="%7D,"vice":%7B"-autostart":"sqdig.prg"%7D%7D)**, usage: `sys49152,n` where `n` is the 0-indexed input.

---

**Intended solution:** (diff)

```
 B9 5B 00 29 0F 95 5B 10 F2 95 5B CA 10 FB A0 20 A2 76 18 B5 E6 90 02 09 10 4A
-95 E6 E8 10 F4 A2 03 76 69 CA 10 FB 88 F0 11 A2 09 B5 5C C9 08 30 04 E9 03 95
+95 E6 E8 10 F4 A2 03 76 69 CA 10 FB 88 F0 11 A2 09 B5 5C C9 08 90 04 E9 03 95
 5C CA 10 F3 30 D6 A2 03 B5 69 95 57 CA 10 F9 A9 01 85 FB A2 03 A9 00 95 FB CA
```

The `30` (opcode `bmi`) is replaced by `90` (opcode `bcc`). This corresponds to the following part in the assembler source:

```
stn_subloop:    lda     nc_string+1,x
                cmp     #$8
                bmi     stn_nosub       ; use bcc here for same result
                sbc     #$3
                sta     nc_string+1,x
```

It works because this code checks whether a number is smaller than 8. The `cmp` instruction performs a subtraction for that, setting the flags accordingly. So, if the accumulator holds a number smaller than 8, this underflows, clearing the carry flag, therefore the correct branch instruction is indeed `bcc`. `bmi` (branching when negative), as in the original code, just happens to work here as well, because the compared numbers are small enough, so the result of the subtraction ends up in the negative range (`$80-$ff`) when an underflow occurs.

**[Online demo](https://vice.janicek.co/c64/#%7B"controlPort2":"joystick","primaryControlPort":2,"keys":%7B"SPACE":"","RETURN":"","F1":"","F3":"","F5":"","F7":""%7D,"files":%7B"sqdig-secret.prg":"data:;base64,AMAg/a6gAJlbAMggcwCQ95lbAKILypiIMAm5WwApD5VbEPKVW8oQ+6AgonYYteaQAgkQSpXm6BD0ogN2acoQ+4jwEaIJtVzJCJAE6QOVXMoQ8zDWogO1aZVXyhD5qQGF+6IDqQCV+8rQ+6IDtfuVIpUmyhD3qQCiA5VpyhD7oCCiAkYldiLKEPuQDKJ8GLWqde2V7egQ96J9BiY2qugQ+4gQ3aILqQCVWsrQ+6Agogm1XMkFMARpApVcyhDzBmmi/TZt6ND7ogm1XCrJECkPlVzKEPSI0NfotVvw+wkwmVsAyOjgC/AEtVuQ8Yi5WwDJMPD4onwYtdvpAJXb6BD3kBSIMAW5WwDQ6qJ89n/QA+gQ+UxowLlbAEzS/w=="%7D,"vice":%7B"-autostart":"sqdig-secret.prg"%7D%7D)**

---

This is an improved/compacted version of [my previous submission](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/147042/71420). Among some other tricks to reduce the size, it removes the useless code that was contained and allowed a kind of "simple"*) crack. All in all, the size is reduced by 16 bytes. This time, it should be a bit harder to find the equivalent program with LD 1 :)

<sup>*) probably still quite some work to find, of course :)</sup>

Again, here's the [`ca65`](http://cc65.github.io/cc65/) assembler source, to help getting started with the code:

```
NUMSIZE         = 4     ; 32 bit integers ...
NUMSTRSIZE      = 11    ; need up to 11 characters for 0-terminated string

.segment "ZPUSR": zeropage
v_x:            .res    NUMSIZE         ; next number to be squared

.segment "ZPFAC": zeropage
v_n:            .res    NUMSIZE         ; input index (0-based), counts down
nc_string:      .res    NUMSTRSIZE      ; string buffer for numbers

.segment "ZPTMP": zeropage
mpm_arg1:       .res    NUMSIZE         ; arg1 for multiplication
mpm_arg2:       .res    NUMSIZE         ; arg2 for multiplication

.segment "ZPFAC2": zeropage
mpm_res:        .res    NUMSIZE         ; numeric result (mult and str convert)

; load address for creating a C64 .PRG file:

.segment "LDADDR"
                .word   $c000

.code

; first read number from command argument and convert to unsigned
; integer in little-endian:

                jsr     $aefd
                ldy     #$00
rn_loop:        sta     nc_string,y
                iny
                jsr     $73
                bcc     rn_loop
                sta     nc_string,y
                ldx     #NUMSTRSIZE
stn_copybcd:    dex
                tya
                dey
                bmi     stn_fillzero
                lda     nc_string,y
                and     #$f
                sta     nc_string,x
                bpl     stn_copybcd
stn_fillzero:   sta     nc_string,x
                dex
                bpl     stn_fillzero
                ldy     #(NUMSIZE*8)
stn_loop:       ldx     #($81-NUMSTRSIZE)
                clc
stn_rorloop:    lda     nc_string+NUMSTRSIZE+$80,x
                bcc     stn_skipbit
                ora     #$10
stn_skipbit:    lsr     a
                sta     nc_string+NUMSTRSIZE+$80,x
                inx
                bpl     stn_rorloop
                ldx     #(NUMSIZE-1)
stn_ror:        ror     mpm_res,x
                dex
                bpl     stn_ror
                dey
                beq     main
stn_sub:        ldx     #(NUMSTRSIZE-2)
stn_subloop:    lda     nc_string+1,x
                cmp     #$8
                bmi     stn_nosub
                sbc     #$3
                sta     nc_string+1,x
stn_nosub:      dex
                bpl     stn_subloop
                bmi     stn_loop

main:
                ldx     #(NUMSIZE-1)
argloop:        lda     mpm_res,x
                sta     v_n,x
                dex
                bpl     argloop
                lda     #$01
                sta     v_x
                ldx     #(NUMSIZE-1)
                lda     #$00
initxloop:      sta     v_x,x
                dex
                bne     initxloop

mainloop:

; prepare arguments for multiplication:

                ldx     #(NUMSIZE-1)
sqrargloop:     lda     v_x,x
                sta     mpm_arg1,x
                sta     mpm_arg2,x
                dex
                bpl     sqrargloop

; do multiplication:

                lda     #$00
                ldx     #(NUMSIZE-1)
mul_clearloop:  sta     mpm_res,x
                dex
                bpl     mul_clearloop
                ldy     #(NUMSIZE*8)
mul_loop:       ldx     #(NUMSIZE-2)
                lsr     mpm_arg1+NUMSIZE-1
mul_rorloop:    ror     mpm_arg1,x
                dex
                bpl     mul_rorloop
                bcc     mul_noadd
                ldx     #($80-NUMSIZE)
                clc
mul_addloop:    lda     mpm_arg2+NUMSIZE+$80,x
                adc     mpm_res+NUMSIZE+$80,x
                sta     mpm_res+NUMSIZE+$80,x
                inx
                bpl     mul_addloop
mul_noadd:      ldx     #($81-NUMSIZE)
                asl     mpm_arg2
mul_rolloop:    rol     mpm_arg2+NUMSIZE+$80,x
                inx
                bpl     mul_rolloop
                dey
                bpl     mul_loop

; convert result to string:

                ldx     #NUMSTRSIZE
                lda     #$0
nts_fillzero:   sta     nc_string-1,x
                dex
                bne     nts_fillzero
                ldy     #(NUMSIZE*8)
nts_bcdloop:    ldx     #(NUMSTRSIZE-2)
nts_addloop:    lda     nc_string+1,x
                cmp     #$5
                bmi     nts_noadd
                adc     #$2
                sta     nc_string+1,x
nts_noadd:      dex
                bpl     nts_addloop
                asl     mpm_res
                ldx     #($ff-NUMSIZE+2)
nts_rol:        rol     mpm_res+NUMSIZE,x       ; + $100 w/o zp wraparound
                inx
                bne     nts_rol
                ldx     #(NUMSTRSIZE-2)
nts_rolloop:    lda     nc_string+1,x
                rol     a
                cmp     #$10
                and     #$f
                sta     nc_string+1,x
nts_rolnext:    dex
                bpl     nts_rolloop
                dey
                bne     nts_bcdloop
nts_scan:       inx
                lda     nc_string,x
                beq     nts_scan
nts_copydigits: ora     #$30
                sta     nc_string,y
                iny
                inx
                cpx     #(NUMSTRSIZE)
                beq     strip0loop
                lda     nc_string,x
                bcc     nts_copydigits

; search for first non-0 character from the end of the string:

strip0loop:     dey
                lda     nc_string,y
                cmp     #$30
                beq     strip0loop

; decrement n for each digit:

founddigit:
                ldx     #($80-NUMSIZE)
                clc
decnloop:       lda     v_n+NUMSIZE+$80,x
                sbc     #$00
                sta     v_n+NUMSIZE+$80,x
                inx
                bpl     decnloop
                bcc     foundresult

                dey
                bmi     next_x
                lda     nc_string,y
                bne     founddigit

; increment x to calculate next square number:

next_x:
                ldx     #($80-NUMSIZE)
incxloop:       inc     v_x+NUMSIZE-$80,x
                bne     incxdone
                inx
                bpl     incxloop
incxdone:       jmp     mainloop

foundresult:    lda     nc_string,y
                jmp     $ffd2
```

... and here's the linker script for `ld65`:

```
MEMORY {
  LDADDR: start = $bffe, size = 2;
  CODE: start = $c000, size = $1000;
  ZPTMP: start = $0022, size = $0008;
  ZPFAC: start = $0057, size = $000f;
  ZPFAC2: start = $0069, size = $0004;
  ZPUSR: start = $00fb, size = $0004;
}

SEGMENTS {
  LDADDR: load = LDADDR;
  CODE: load = CODE;
  ZPTMP: load = ZPTMP, type = zp;
  ZPFAC: load = ZPFAC, type = zp;
  ZPFAC2: load = ZPFAC2, type = zp;
  ZPUSR: load = ZPUSR, type = zp;
}
```

Comment: Consider it un-cracked :)

Comment: @Jo. well if you insist -- thanks a lot, I edited it.

Answer (score 1):

### Lua : LD=1, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/146927/levenshtein-distance-oeis-robbers/146935#146935)

```
i=1s=""while(#s<...+0)do s=s..((i*i)..""):reverse():gsub("(0+)(%d+)$","%2")i=i+1 end print(s:sub(...,...))
```

No fancy tricks here :)

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/146935/41024)

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, LD=43 [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/146967/67961)

```
Flatten[Table[(k=IntegerDigits)@FromDigits@Reverse@k[i^2],{i,10^4}]][[#]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zgq/DfLSexpCQ1LzokMSknNVoj29YzryQ1PbXIJTM9s6RY08GtKD8XwnYISi1LLSpOdciOzowzitWpztQxNIgzqY2NjY5Wjo1V@x9QlJlXouCQFm0UZ2ga@x8A)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/146967/74672).

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, LD = 35 ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/147591/75557))

1-indexed

```
<?while(strlen($s)<$argv[1])$s.=(int)strrev(++$i*$i);echo substr($s,$argv[1]-1,1);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ncs9CoAwDEDhqzhkaPzDzioeRBxUig1IW5qqtzd2cX2PL9ggMkyPpdMoTvE0TgHjAGs87lkvCNyOilzCPKO5VVUBlUDYm936gq8t9yzqHzS61tiLiO6614dE3rE07gM)

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3: LD = 9 | [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/146932/68942)

```
lambda i:"".join(str(k*k+2*k+1)[::-1].lstrip("0")for k in range(i+1))[i]
```

This one should be fairly (very) easy to get :P

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/146932/59487).

Comment: I deleted my Crack because the original answer is invalid.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder You can undelete now; LD is the same because the `.lstrip("0")` part can just be copied over.

Comment: [Done](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/146932/59487)

Answer (score 0):

## [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/), 61 bytes (LD = 23)

```
{(1..it).collect{0.valueOf("${it**2}".reverse())}.join()[it]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFRCoAgDADQu0gfmx9Du0gHiD5CVixEw5YQ4tntvbPkXL9xF0kKMBp4IlGkkGPkoM1R3ePLywFmaqLWzt1Q4crlYUDsdGVJgKvo1geCd4jjBw)

Comment: How is this safe >_>...

Answer (score 0):

## C++, LD = 159

0-indexed, input in `argv[1]`, compiled on GCC 7.2.0

```cpp
#import<bits/stdc++.h>
char*h,b[1<<17],*q=b;int x,y;main(int,char**j){sscanf(j[1],"%d",&y);do{x++;q+=sprintf(h=q,"%d",x*x);while(*--q==48);std::reverse(h,++q);}while(q-b<=y);b[y+1]=0,printf(b+y);}
```